# How to change button to normal string

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

How do I change this button question mark to just to a regular text question mark when clickin on it ?

`<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="About Company">?</button>`

Here is picture what I'm trying to achieve!

[image]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/daWzY.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<body>
    <div id="myDiv">
        <input type="button" value="?" id="submit" onClick="change()"> <!--button input that will trigger an event named change-->
    </div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">

function change(){ //function to run when you click on the button...
    var valueOfButton = document.getElementById("submit").value; 
    //create a variable with the value of the submit button
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = valueOfButton; 
    // Here we are changing the value of myDiv. Replace the button with plain text.
}

</script>
```

How do you want to achieve this? 
And what have you tried?
I have just a simple solution.

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly what I was looking for! :)